# Rarely get 4G service on my HTC Rezound

Tags: connection-issues, verizon, 4g, htc-rezound

I rarely get 4G service on my HTC Rezound. I live in a city with plenty of access (Washington, DC) and visit cities which should also have access (Los Angeles, Chicago, and New York) and yet no matter where I am, the 4G is rarely active.

I have taken in my phone several times to Verizon, and all they do is replace the sim card.

What else can it be???

Thanks!

Comment: Have you updated to Android 4.0 (ICS) yet? I know that resolved most issues with my wife's.

Comment: @ZnewmaN thanks, but it's already on ICS